# Search and Filtering Data in Reactjs Firestore v9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to implement a debounce search function by filtering data in firestore like the following figure.

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24caZ.png)

And here is my document at Firestore:

[image: Document]

I have try to use `startAt()` combining with `orderBy()` function in firestore to get a list of children node. Below is my code:

```
const searchTitle = async (e) => {
  onSnapshot(query(collection(db, 'reports'), orderBy('title'), startAt(`${e.target.value}`)), snapshot => {
    setCurrentItem(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
      id: doc.id,
      data: doc.data()
    })))
  })
}
```

And my implement code with UI:

```
<form  style={{ display: "inline" }}>
       <input
        type="text"
        className="inputField"
        placeholder="Search Title"
        onChange={searchTitle}
        value={search}
        />
</form>
```

Display the result

```
   <tbody>
       {currentItem.map((currentItem) =>{
           return (
              <tr>
                 <td>{currentItem.data.dateCreate}</td>
                 <td>{currentItem.data.title}</td>
                 <td>{currentItem.data.creator}</td>
                 <td>{currentItem.data.type}</td>
                 <td>{currentItem.data.status}</td>
              </tr>   
       )})}
  </tbody>
```

Please someone could help me to figure out this.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working here? Are there any errors?

Comment: @Dharmaraj it seems that it did no return a right value that i am searching for

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the document that you think should match the query? And also have you logged and checked the value of `e.target.value` ?/

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have attached the UI of my code. So the idea is to let user input on the search title bar and return the list of nearly matching with the input

Comment: @ChrisHo We're looking for a screenshot of a document that you'd expect the query to return in the Firebase console.  That way we can see the fields and values in a way that we're all familiar with, without having to understand how your code presents that in your application UI.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited the post and update the document screenshot, and also my code when I tried to implemented it

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still not entirely sure what the problem is though. 1) If you `print('${e.target.value}')` inside `searchTitle`, what does it output? 2) What isn't working abut the code? Are you not getting the document for which you shared a screenshot? Or are you getting more documents than you expected?